# Unable to start activity

Tags: android

Am a beginner in android while adding a new class in an existing project it not running and showing a message like unfortunately app get stopped.
What is the reason for this problem?.How can i solve it?.

Its my manifest

```
    <activity
android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.parthi"
android:label="@string/title_activity_parthi" >
</activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

its my activity

```
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class parthi extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parthi);
    }
}
   08-07 12:12:38.530  28908-28908/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-07 12:12:41.562  28908-28908/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sentientit.theiWedplanner, PID: 28908
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.parthi}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:149)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.parthi.onCreate(parthi.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: can you post some crash logs?

Comment: add your logcat out put here

Comment: Post your logcat.. Then only some one can help you.

Comment: wati 2 mts i 'll post it

Comment: include activity to manifest file

Comment: The log is quite clear:
   ` java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.parthi}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`
post your manifest.

Comment: i 've posted my manifest

Comment: @parthibanR, Post your full manifest.

Comment: remove this --> public class parthi extends ActionBarActivity and use this -->public class parthi extends Activity

Comment: thank you @darshil Shak its working,But i like know the reason for not accessing the class

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your inheritence from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Extend your activity class with 'AppCompatActivity'.

Add Your activity class in manifest file.

like:

```
 <activity
        android:name="packageName.className"/>
```

Comment: i tried it but no improvement

Comment: What you have tried..can you post your code of manifest as well as your activity class.

Comment: I posted it make read on it

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat throws

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.parthi}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

### How Would you

Since the version 22.1.0, the class [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is deprecated. You should use [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) or [Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Comment: thank you its working.I would like to know the reason for the trouble at initial state

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding

Comment: Please read this article http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: @parthibanR  You can also set this as an accepted answer

Comment: Sry am a new user tell me how to set as accepted answer

Comment: Click "Right" Button

Comment: @parthibanR http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 way to solve this issue:

1. Change your `parthi` to extends `Activity` or `FragmentActivy`.
2. If you still want to extends from `ActionBarActivity`, goto your styles.xml, make sure your application's style has parent start with `Theme.AppCompat.`(check it in all the values folders) or in Manifest, add theme for this activity: 
   `<activity
           android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.parthi}"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />`

Hope this helps.